# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'patches'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, attributeerror

**My data set:**

```
weather = pd.read_csv('https://coded2.herokuapp.com/datavizpandas/london2018.csv')

weather.head(3)
```

I can't add label point to label `subplots=True, layout=(2,2) 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'patches'`

Can anyone help me for this issues?

```
{ ax=weather.plot(kind='bar',y=['Tmax','Tmin','Rain','Sun'], 
x='Month',subplots=True)
for i in ax.patches:
ax.text(i.get_x(),i.get_height()+0.21,str(round(i.get_height())),
fontsize=10)
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','july','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
plt.show()}
```

Comment: did you add a patch to your ax already ?

Comment: I don't know how to add patches to my ax

Comment: This code is working well.
ax = weather.plot(kind='bar',y=['Tmax','Tmin'],x='Month',figsize=(16.5, 8.5))
after addin subplot to ax it doesn’t work well.
Thank you